# how to search in a ArrayList?

Tags: java

I have to search a contact by name, surname or telephone number.
how can i do that?
I think i can't use java 8 stream in this case...
Another thing... I have to press "2" two times in order to see all the contact list but the if implementation seems right to me.

The code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test1 {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
    ArrayList<Contatto> cont = new ArrayList<Contatto>();
    int a;
    try{
        while (true){
            System.out.println("Per inserire nuovo contatto premere 1");
            System.out.println("Per visionare l'elenco dei contatti premere 2");
            System.out.println("Per cercare un contatto premere 3");
            a= in.nextInt();
            //if you press1 you add new contact
            if (a == 1){
                cont.add(new Contatto()); 
            }
            //if you press2 you'll see all the contact list.
            else if (a == 2){
                for (Contatto tmp : cont){
                    String tm = tmp.dammiDettagli(tmp);
                    System.out.println(tm);
                }
            }
            //if you press 3 you'll be able to search a contact by name or
            //surname or telephone number
            else if (a == 3){
                System.out.println("Cerca contatto:");
                }
            else {
                System.out.println("Inserimento dati errato");
                }
            }

    }finally {
        in.close();
    }
}       
}
```

and this is the public class Contatto:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Contatto {
private String nome;
private String cognome;
private String num_Tel;
Contatto(){
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println("Creazione nuovo contatto...");
        System.out.println("Inserire il nome:");
        //set name
        setNome(in.next()); 
        System.out.println("Inserire il cognome:");
        //set surname
        setCognome(in.next());
        System.out.println("Inserire il numero di telefono:");
        //set telephone number
        setNum_Tel(in.next());
}
//method to search contact
public String cercaContatto(String in){
}
public String dammiDettagli(Contatto contatto){
    return getNome() +" "+ getCognome() +" "+ getNum_Tel();
}
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getCognome() {
    return cognome;
}
public void setCognome(String cognome) {
    this.cognome = cognome;
}
public String getNum_Tel() {
    return num_Tel;
}
public void setNum_Tel(String num_Tel) {
    this.num_Tel = num_Tel;
}
}
```

Comment: Each time you use `nextInt()` you attempt to read int from console. So don't do that in `if` statement. To it once and store result like `int choice = in.nextInt()` and then use that stored value in conditions like `if (choice == 1){..} else if (choice == 2){..}`. You can also use `switch/case` here.

Comment: if i store the result i won't be able to change that value.,. i have used the while(true){..} because i wanted to remake that choice.

Comment: You can, just read once inside of your loop. This will let you update that value in each iteration.

Comment: Thanks! it worked fine! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done in Java 8 as next:

```
Optional<Contatto> result = cont.stream().filter(c ->
    (nome == null || nome.equalsIgnoreCase(c.getNome()))
        && (cognome == null || cognome.equalsIgnoreCase(c.getCognome()))
        && (num_Tel == null || num_Tel.equals(c.getNum_Tel()))
).findFirst();
```

Assuming that `nome`, `cognome` and `num_Tel` are `String` representing your query's criteria.

If `nome`, `cognome` and `num_Tel` are `Optional<String>` representing your query's criteria, it will then be:

```
Optional<Contatto> result = cont.stream().filter(c ->
    nome.map(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase(c.getNome())).orElse(true)
        && cognome.map(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase(c.getCognome())).orElse(true)
        && num_Tel.map(s -> s.equals(c.getNum_Tel())).orElse(true)
).findFirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Add a method for each type of search that you are performing and call that method in choice "3". The method is simple and pretty straightforward, for example, for searching by phone number

```
private static Contatto SearchContattoNumber( ArrayList<Contatto> cont, int number ) {
  for (Contatto tmp : cont){
    if (tmp.getNum_Tel() == number) return tmp;
  }
  return null;
}
```

And you would create such a method for each Search option, and then decide which search you're gonna use by asking the user just like you did ask for what operation you will perform